# How to get offset in Google Maps iframe embed

Tags: google-maps

I embed a Google Maps view on my website, but the point is always centered. However, I want to move the point a bit to the left.

I already tried adding &ll to the end of the url, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3153.3898312892516!2d-122.39498068385242!3d37.78090297975824!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x808580787b995e7f%3A0x573dcb3f41440563!2sDropbox!5e0!3m2!1snl!2sbe!4v1565976484287!5m2!1snl!2sbe" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So the cursor with 'Dropbox' is centralized, but I would need it to be on the left side of the map (while still having the pointer on Dropbox). How can I do this?

Got the embed iframe code from Google Maps. Searched the location, clicked 'share' in the left side panel and chose 'embed'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can customize the output of the default Google Maps "share" output.  I tried adjusting the map before getting the "Embed a Map" code, it doesn't modify it.

An option would be the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide), that has an optional `center` parameter that lets you adjust the center of the map.

Using the ["Place mode"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#place_mode) with the optional "center" parameter:

```
q=Dropbox,333+Brannan+St,+San+Francisco,+CA+94107&center=37.7810556,-122.389
```

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=Dropbox,333+Brannan+St,+San+Francisco,+CA+94107&center=37.7810556,-122.389" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

gives me:

[image: screenshot of resulting iframe]

[live example](http://geocodezip.com/embed_example_centerParam.html)